# creating a filter with pagination with golang for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a large filter and I will provide a snippet of it. I am trying to pass a map of the filter with paganization but I get an error that reads

```
the match filter must be an expression in an object
```

---

getting the filter

---

```
    func (app *Courses) getFilter(filter *Filter) ([]bson.M, error) {
    
        pipeline := make([]bson.M, 0)
    
        if filter.All {
            // Include all items
        } else {
            // Filter items based on the provided criteria
            if filter.Beginner {
                pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"tags": "beginner"})
            }
            if filter.Advanced {
                pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"tags": "advanced"})
            }
            if filter.Go {
                pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"tags": "go"})
            }
        }
    
        return pipeline, nil
    }
```

---

Handler

---

```
func (app *Courses) CoursesAllHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    clog := log.GetLoggerFromContext(ctx)

    p := r.URL.Query().Get("page")
    ps := r.URL.Query().Get("pageSize")

    var filter Filter
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&filter)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to parse request body", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    pipeline := make([]bson.M, 0)

    page, _ := strconv.Atoi(p)
    pageSize, _ := strconv.Atoi(ps)

    // Pagination
    skip := (page - 1) * pageSize
    limit := pageSize

    // Add filter
    pipeline, err = app.getFilter(&filter)
    if err != nil {
        clog.Error(err)
    }
    pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"$match": pipeline})

    // Add pagination stages to the pipeline
    pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"$skip": skip})
    pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"$limit": limit})

    res, err := app.repo.GetAll(ctx, pipeline)
    if err != nil {
        clog.Error(err)

        return
    }

    err = app.helper.WriteJSON(w, http.StatusOK, envelope{"data": res, "metadata": "none"}, nil)
    if err != nil {
        clog.ErrorCtx(err, log.Ctx{
            "header":      w.Header(),
            "request_url": r.URL.String(),
        })
    }

}
```

How can I get the values set "true" or "false", put them in a map and submit them in the query to be matched the DB like I am trying to do here.

```
// Add filter
pipeline, err = app.getFilter(&filter)
if err != nil {
    clog.Error(err)
}
pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"$match": pipeline})
```

---- update ----

I now have:

```
func (app *Courses) CoursesAllHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := context.Background()

clog := log.GetLoggerFromContext(ctx)

var filter Filter
err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&filter)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Failed to parse request body", http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

filter.All = true

pipeline := make([]bson.M, 3)

// Add filter
matches, err := app.getFilter(&filter)
if err != nil {
    clog.Error(err)
}

pipeline[0] = bson.M{"$skip": 1}
pipeline[1] = bson.M{"$limit": 5}
pipeline[2] = bson.M{"$match": matches}


res, err := app.repo.GetAll(ctx, pipeline)
if err != nil {
    clog.Error(err)

    return
}

err = app.helper.WriteJSON(w, http.StatusOK, envelope{"data": res, "metadata": "none"}, nil)
if err != nil {
    clog.ErrorCtx(err, log.Ctx{
        "header":      w.Header(),
        "request_url": r.URL.String(),
    })
 }

}
```

and the filter looks like

```
func (app *Courses) getFilter(filter *Filter) (bson.M, error) {

    match := bson.M{}
    tags := []string{}

    if filter.All {
        // Include all items
        tags = append(tags, "beginner")
        tags = append(tags, "intermediate")
        .....
    } else {
        // Filter items based on the provided criteria
        if filter.Beginner {
            tags = append(tags, "beginner")
        }
        if filter.Advanced {
            tags = append(tags, "advanced")
        }
        if filter.Go {
            tags = append(tags, "go")
        }
        ........

    }

    match = bson.M{
        "tags": bson.M{"$in": tags},
    }

    return match, nil
}
```

which is later used here..

```
func (r *CourseRepo) GetAll(ctx context.Context, pipeline []bson.M) ([]Course, error) {
    clog := log.GetLoggerFromContext(ctx)

    cur, err := r.collection.Aggregate(ctx, pipeline)

    ...
```

However it is empty. Everything is selected in the filter and there is no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `the match filter must be an expression in an object` because the `$match` expecting an object (`bson.M`) but you have given `slice of objects ([]bson.M)`.

Try this

```
func (app *Courses) getFilter(filter *Filter) (bson.M, error) {
    match := bson.M{}
    tags := []string{}

    if filter.All {
        // Include all items
    } else {
        // Filter items based on the provided criteria
        if filter.Beginner {
            tags = append(tags, "beginner")
        }
        if filter.Advanced {
            tags = append(tags, "advanced")

        }
        if filter.Go {
            tags = append(tags, "go")
        }

        match = bson.M{
            "tags": bson.M{"$in": tags},
        }
    }

    return match, nil
}
```

Comment: this would just override the filter unless only one thing was selected and when it is used it needs the slice `cur, err := r.collection.Aggregate(ctx, pipeline)`

Comment: You can use `$in` to allow multiple tags. Just updated the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I am trying to confirm. I am working though `cur, err := r.collection.Aggregate(ctx, pipeline)` this part right now. `can only marshal slices and arrays into aggregation pipelines, but got map`. Hope to accept the answer shortly

Comment: I updated the post. Is this what you meant? I do not get a response. I am wondering if it is my code I mixed the query again.

Comment: `pipeline[2] = bson.M{"$match": bson.M{}}` Can you try like this and check response having all the documents or not?

Comment: I needed to have `"topic": bson.M{"$in": tags},` not `tags`